# is(:hover) alternative for ie & firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I a have a menu, which on rollover shows a div which is not a child of the menu and when you roll off it hides that div again. The div is placed directly below the menu item, mimicking a submenu.

the html looks something like this -

Here is my menu -

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li class='with_panel'>
      <span id='panel1' class='current'><img src='theImage' /></span>
    </li>
    <!-- more list items -->
</ul>
</div>
```

In an unrelated div, I have this -

```
<div id="panels">
     <div style="" id="panel1_panel" class="panel">
        <img src="myImage.png">
     </div>
<div>
```

I have some jquery that shows and hides the related panel when you rollover the li -

```
$("#nav .with_panel").mouseenter(function(){
    var id = $(this).find("span").attr("id");
    $(".panel").removeClass("open");
    $panel = $("#" + id + "_panel");
    $panel.addClass("open");
    $img = $(this).find("span img");
    $img.addClass("on");
    var hide = function(){
    if(!$panel.is(":hover")){
            $img.removeClass("on");
            $panel.removeClass("open");
        }
    }

    $panel.mouseleave(hide);
    $(this).mouseleave(hide);   
})
```

This only seems to work in Chrome, and I'm fairly certain it's due to ie & Firefox not recognising .is(":hover").

I can't change the html structure, only the javascript. So I'm struggling on getting it to work cross browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the CSS that goes along with this?  A working example would be good too if you have one.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldnt just use the .hover event in this situation rather than mouseenter?

Comment: Can't get a working version up at the mo, I'm afraid. The CSS is quite simple, the panel hugs the nav list directly below on rollover and is repositioned away from it on rollout. I'll try and edit my question to show the css soon enough.

Comment: No reason why I'm not using hover, but apart from cutting code would it make a difference?

Comment: Try using different events for mouseenter/mouserleave. Like mouseover, hover, etc. Unfortunately, some of them don't work well on all browsers. =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code gives you 200 ms timeout (`hide_to`) to leave the menu and enter your panel before hiding it. Works the other way too. If you mouseenter the menuitem or the panel the timeout for the hiding is cancelled, and restarted when the mouse leaves any of them.

```
$("#nav .with_panel").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).find("span").attr("id"),
        $panel = $("#" + id + "_panel"),
        $img = $(this).find("span img"),
        hide_to = null;

    var hide = function() {
            // start hide timeout
            hide_to = window.setTimeout(function () {
                $img.removeClass("on");
                $panel.removeClass("open");
            },200);
        };

    var show = function() {
            // clear hide timeout
            window.clearTimeout(hide_to);
            if (!$panel.is(".open"))
            {
                // open panel, only if it is not open already
                $(".panel").removeClass("open");
                $panel.addClass("open");
                $img.addClass("on");
            }
        };

    $(this).mouseenter(function() {
        show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        hide();
    });

    $panel.mouseenter(function() {
        show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's fixed it in firefox, I've not had a chance to test in Ie yet. You have a slight error in your code on the hide_to timeout. I've not edited you answer as I'm not sure of the etiquette in doing so. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the error? I would correct it myself, but I cannot see it.

Comment: I'm getting 'SyntaxError: missing : after property id' in firefox  when trying to run your hide_to timeout. I wrapped it in a function and removed the brackets - hide_to = window.setTimeout(removeClasses,50);

Comment: corrected, I forgot to add `function ()` inside the `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 2):

Try mouseover instead of mouseenter and mouseout instead of mouseleave.

For example:

```
$("#nav .with_panel").mouseover(function(){
    var id = $(this).find("span").attr("id");
    $(".panel").removeClass("open");
    $panel = $("#" + id + "_panel");
    $panel.addClass("open");
    $img = $(this).find("span img");
    $img.addClass("on");
        var hide = function(){
    if(!$panel.is(":hover")){
            $img.removeClass("on");
            $panel.removeClass("open");
        }
    }

    $panel.mouseout(hide);
    $(this).mouseout(hide);   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that .is(":hover") is actually broken for *all* browsers, as of jQuery 1.9.1. Bummer. The following is tested with FF, IE10, and Chrome (sorry don't have Opera) with jQuery 1.9.1. Opera users, please comment on whether this works on Opera.

```
function isHovered(elt){
    var temp = $(elt).parent().find(":hover");
    return temp.length == 1 && temp[0] == elt;
}
```

Then replace

```
$panel.is(":hover")
```

by

```
isHovered($panel[0])
```

otherwise, leave all your code as is.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mathheadinclouds/BxL4w/